# Shared element transition blocked by other views

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, android-animation

I'm attempting to implement a shared element transition where I share some text from one fragment to another. The actual shared element animation worked fine until I attempted to combine it with a `Fade` transition. Now the shared element is being hidden behind the other fading content and is only visible once the fade finishes.

I'm animating from fragment A to fragment B.

In fragment A, I'm setting the `exitTransition` property in `onCreate` like so:

```
exitTransition = Fade()
```

In fragment B, I'm setting the `enterTransition` property in `onCreate` as well:

```
enterTransition = Fade()
```

The actual shared element transition is being triggered in the containing activity:

```
supportFragmentManager.commit {
      replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, FragmentB.newInstance())
      addSharedElement(sharedView, "transition_name")
      setReorderingAllowed(true)
      addToBackStack(null)
    }
```

The animation used for the shared element is being set in `onCreate` of fragment B:

```
TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);

Transition changeBounds = new ChangeBounds();
changeBounds.addTarget(R.id.logo);
changeBounds.addTarget("logo_transition_name");
set.addTransition(changeBounds);

ChangeTransform changeTransform = new ChangeTransform();
changeTransform.addTarget(R.id.logo);
changeTransform.addTarget("logo_transition_name");
set.addTransition(changeTransform);

Transition textSize = new TextSizeTransition();
textSize.addTarget(R.id.logo);
textSize.addTarget("logo_transition_name");
set.addTransition(textSize);

sharedElementEnterTransition = set;
```

What am I missing?

Here's a gif for reference:

[image: example-gif]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I managed to fix this issue by setting a `scale` on the logo `TextView` that was transitioning.

To elaborate, my understanding from previous stack overflow answers written by George Mount is that the `ChangeTransform` transition will (kind of magically) handle reparenting a shared element view such that it won't get drawn over by another view.

After debugging the `ChangeTransform` transition, I found that its `createAnimator` method was never being called. It looks like that's because the view being shared didn't have any scale or rotation changes between the fragment A and fragment B.

Setting a scale of 0.99 on the logo `TextView` in fragment A lead to the `createAnimator` method being called and the view properly transitioning *over* other views instead of under them.

I *suspect* that since people are normally sharing imageviews that theres normally a scale difference between the two images so this problem doesn't show up as much. I could be wrong about that.